# Удаление переменных из памяти

Tags: java, variable

У меня есть две переменные. Одна ссылочная, и вторая примитив. Они обе обернуты в поле видимости. И вопрос такой: "Когда этот блок заканчивается, то переменные и значения находящиеся в них уничтожаются (*ссылка больше не встречается ни где*)?"

```
public class Test {
    public static void main() {
        {
            String str = "apple";
            System.out.println(str);  //apple
            int num = 1;
            System.out.println(num);  //1
        }

        {
            String str = "tomato";
            System.out.println(str);  //tomato
            int num = 38;
            System.out.println(num);  //38
        }
    }
}
```

То есть на момент вывода "tomato" в памяти будет только "tomato" и 38 или все 4 значения?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю - "да",  при выходе из области видимости и отсутствии ссылок на переменную, она помечается для удаления сборщиком мусора. В памяти она или нет, зависит от сборщика мусора, т.к. он выполняет сборку не сразу-же, а согласно куче условий/алгоритмов и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Небольшое замечание

Не относится к вопроосу, но скажу, что при попытке запустить класс `Test` у вас появиться ошибка:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Test, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Так как вы забыли добавить `String[] args` в параметры метода `main`.

#### Ваш вопрос

Переменные в каком либо блоке (методе, инициализаторе, конструкторе, цикле и т.д.) - *локальные переменные* за пределами этого самого блока не видны. И если блок выполнился, то все эти переменные уничтожаются, как верно заметил @XelaNimed в комментарии. Ведь их всё равно ниоткуда не достать, то есть ссылок на них быть не может.

Доказательство:

- За пределами блока видимости к переменной получить доступ нельзя. То есть ссылки на неё удалены:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            String str = "apple";
            System.out.println(str);  
        }
        System.out.println(str); //Ошибка: cannot find symbol
    }
}
```

Но что же будет, если блок, где объявляется переменная будет запущен ещё раз?
 Давайте подробно посмотрим на происходящее:

1. Блок запускается в первый раз.
2. Блок завершает свою работу. Все переменные и ссылки на них удаляются.
3. Блок запускается ещё раз.
4. Переменные **создаются заново**. Ведь старых переменных как бы не существует, они и ссылки на них уже удалены.